# Export plots to pdf with bookmark for each plot

Tags: r, pdf

I'm trying to export multiple plots (about 30 or so) into a single pdf file - the catch is that I would really like bookmarks for each plot, so that it's easier to navigate in the pdf. The plots are created with `ggplot2` .
I know I can export all plots at once with `pdf("myfile.pdf")` and `dev.off()` , or each plot to its own file with `ggsave` but adding bookmarks  *in* the pdf file is beyond me.

Any ideas?

Comment: Try using Rmarkdown. Create a single chapter per plot. This should bring you the bookmarks.

Comment: I had a similar problem a while back and the brew package worked great. I don't know how much latex you know, but if you learn a little latex and the brew package to create the repetitive report, it's super easy.

Comment: Floo0 - totally forgot about Rmarkdown. It gets the job done pretty well, although installing the Tex software package is quite a pain.